# Does blender have a layout system for architectural modeling?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I just started a modern house project and I want to start with a layout of the house. Is there any feature in Blender that basically lets you draw your layout?

(Sorry if this question is a no brainer, I am new to architect in Blender)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you defining as a 'layout'?

Comment: @RayMairlot something that would let me layout all of the rooms I want in my house

Comment: If you are asking about doing some type of blueprints, I think that is best done in Photoshop/GIMP. However if you want to do this is Blender this should get you started. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSqiswfVb5k

Comment: Could you better explain what the capabilities of the add-on would be? There are many ways you can speed up the modeling, the choiche depends on your needs. Did you already tried archimesh add-on? https://youtu.be/IoMeS5ZpfXw?t=5m24s

Comment: I think Achimesh is what you are looking for: https://www.blendernation.com/2015/07/10/archimesh-1-1-adds-flexible-editing/

Comment: @icYou520 I am trying to model a house that I have in my head. Not something based off reference material. (I lost some of my reputation for posting an answer that relies on YouTube links)

Comment: @Carlo I am trying to find something that will help me layout my house. (Kinda like blueprints)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Archimesh addon](https://www.blendernation.com/2015/07/10/archimesh-1-1-adds-flexible-editing/). It is included as part of blender just needs to be enabled in the System Preferences window.

As described in the [github page](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/archimesh):

Is Blender add-on for creating architecture elements:
Rooms, Houses, Columns , Stairs, Doors, Windows, Tile roofs, Kitchen cabinets, Japanese curtains, Roller curtains, Venetian blinds, Books, Lamps

Comment: Thanks! I clicked on the GitHub page. I cannot find a download button though... (I am sorta new to add ons too)

Comment: You don't need to download it, it is part of blender. Just enable the addon.

Comment: How do I enable the grease pencil?

Comment: New questions should be asked on a separate post.